# How can I get the min/max possible numeric?

Tags: r

Is there a function that returns the highest and lowest possible numeric values?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`help(numeric)` sends you to `help(double)` which has

> Double-precision values:
>
> ```
>  All R platforms are required to work with values conforming tothe
>  IEC 60559 (also known as IEEE 754) standard.  This basically works
>  with a precision of 53 bits, and represents to that precision a
>  range of absolute values from about 2e-308 to 2e+308.  It also has
>  special values ‘NaN’ (many of them), plus and minus infinity and
>  plus and minus zero (although R acts as if these are the same).
>  There are also _denormal(ized)_ (or _subnormal_) numbers with
>  absolute values above or below the range given above but
>  represented to less precision.
>
>  See ‘.Machine’ for precise information on these limits.  Note that
>  ultimately how double precision numbers are handled is down to the
>  CPU/FPU and compiler.
> ```

So you want to look at `.Machine` which on my 64-bit box has

```
$double.xmin
[1] 2.22507e-308

$double.xmax
[1] 1.79769e+308
```

Comment: much appreciated!  .Machine is new to me...good stuff to know!

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if these values were different on any mainstream OS ... the bit-ness of the OS doesn't affect whether numerics are stored as double precision floats ...

Answer (score -1):

```
help("numeric")
```

will ask you to do

```
help("double)
```

which will give the answer: range of absolute values from about 2e-308 to 2e+308.