# How to write a function with an specific interval for the first 10 numbers then a new interval for the second 10 and so on using R

Tags: r, function, sequence, seq

I want to get all the numbers with an increase like this `10^(seq(1,9,by=1))` then the next 10 `10^(seq(10,90,by=10))` ... `10^(seq(a,b,by=a))`

Comment: After `10^(seq(10,90,by=10))` would it be `10^(seq(100,900,by=100))` ? Most of the numbers in that vector become infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code like below

```
c(sapply(10**(0:log10(a)),function(x) 10**seq(x,9*x,by = x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, thus is what you are looking for:

```r
get_pwr <- function(a) {
  b <- 10^a - a
  10^(seq(a, b, by=a))
}

lapply(seq(1,9,by=1), get_pwr)
```

bur remember the limitation of the sizes: [R in a 64 bit world](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-in-a-64-bit-world/)

and [the-min-max-possible-numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504463/how-can-i-get-the-min-max-possible-numeric)

Comment: I think you mean `b <- 10^a - a`?  (Otherwise, the end of one list is duplicated by the start of the next.) And maybe wrap the `lapply` in `unlist`?