# sinh() returning inf in R

Tags: r, scaling, inf

If I do `sinh(1000)` I get `Inf`, which it seems is expected, but I am curious to know if there are any ways to overcome this?

I tried: `format(round(sinh(1000), 2), nsmall = 2)` believing it is a decimal issue, but maybe my issue is more conceptual, than technical?

I just found it strange that `sinh(700)` works well but fails on numbers near enough above this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7504524/9463489) answer. `numeric` objects in R can only get so big. The inverse `sinh` is approximately `log(x) + log(2)` for large `x`:

```
> .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
> sinh(log(.Machine$double.xmax) + log(2))
[1] 1.797693e+308
> sinh(log(.Machine$double.xmax) + log(2) + 1e-10)
[1] Inf
```

A common approach is to work in log-space. `log(sinh(x))` for large `x` is approximately `x - log(2)`:

```
> log(sinh(700))
[1] 699.3069
> 700 - log(2)
[1] 699.3069
> log(sinh(700)) - 700 + log(2)
[1] 5.495604e-14
```

If you clarify what you are trying to do with numbers larger than `sinh(700)`, someone may have additional ideas to work around your problem.

Comment: wonderful -- thank you for the input!